# Font Not applying in React Application

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am importing fonts from google fonts and applying that fonts on all elements of index page.

But not applying these fonts

**In index.html**

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

**index.css**

```
 .body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P'; }
```

Comment: Do you really have an element that has `class="body"`?

Comment: @GuyIncognito probably he is applying this `font` on class `body` not on `<body>` tag

Answer (score 1):

See this works, maybe you are trying to change in the body tag, replace `.body` with `body`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap');
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
}
```

```html
Hello World!
```